# any tips for convenient including third-party library by Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

Currently I have a project developed based on several C++ third-party libraries, such as
Eigen,vtk. For convenience, I install these libraries in the standard path, e.g. 
/usr/local/include/eigen3, /usr/local/include/vtk-6.2.
In this case, I do not need to add extra paths in eclipse project.

And in Eclipse project, I can include them like this:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>

#include <vtk-6.2/vtkAutoInit.h>
```

Now my question is: How to include these libraries simply like this:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
```

that is, libraries installed in /usr/local/include or /usr/include as a sub folder? Thanks!

Comment: In your project settings you can add include paths, like e.g. `/usr/local/include/eigen3`, then that path will be searched by default when you include header files.

Comment: Many librarys use `pkg-config` to tell the build system where to find the headers and libraries. I use a plugin for eclipse that inperfaces with the `pkg-config` system so all you have to do is select the library from a list: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pkg-config-support-eclipse-cdt . It won't work for everything though.